# fetching record from database matching by date where date field is in varchar

Tags: php, mysql, date

i have a table of adds in my database and i define a field date with each record which has a type of varchar and srores date in date format. i insert value in date field by using now() function and my date field has value in format

> 2012-10-07 14:00:54

i want to fetch the records matching by date of today,yesterday,last week and last month but i dont know how to do this. i searched on google alot and i tried many functions but its not working i run the following queries

```
select * from adds where date(date_sub(now(), interval 0 day))
   select * from adds where date(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day))
   select * from adds where date(date_sub(now(), interval 7 day))
   select * from adds where date(date_sub(now(), interval 31 day))
```

all these are not working and i also tried

```
select * from adds where date=curdate()
  select * from adds where date=current_date()
```

please guide me how can i fetch records.
i am using localhost server xampp win32 1.7.7

Comment: It is possible to work around this, but it would be *much* better to use a proper DATETIME field. Why can you not make it a DATETIME field?

Comment: my teacher said to me to use varcher instead of datetime type

Comment: can i not match date by using varchar???

Comment: Yes, you can; it is a bit more expensive, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to fetch the records matching by date of today,yesterday,last
>   week and last month but i dont know how to do this.

Then you need to `SELECT` those records where the date is between the bounds:

```
SELECT * FROM adds WHERE `date`
      BETWEEN
          DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
      AND DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 0 DAY))
;
```

The above ought to give you last week, ending at today's beginning at 00:00.

Note: the above works if the varchar date syntax is the same as MySQL. If it is not, you need to specifically instruct MySQL as how to parse it:

```
  WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`,'%Y:%d:%m %H:%i:%s') BETWEEN..
```

See [`date_format()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for the date format syntax.

Comment: SELECT * FROM adds WHERE `date`
      BETWEEN
          DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
      AND DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 0 DAY))

Comment: this query works but shows only the record of last week not including today plz tell me how to fetch the records of today and last month i edit the above query interval 7 to 30 but it not show me the last months records

Comment: sorry i am at mistake the above query is fetching the records of last month and last week but not today as you said "ending at today's beginning at 00:00." i want the records of todays till end of the day till 24:00